# How to use PNASNet5 as encoder in Unet in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, image-segmentation, encoder

I want use PNASNet5Large as encoder for my Unet here is my wrong aproach for the PNASNet5Large but working for resnet:

```
class UNetResNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, encoder_depth, num_classes, num_filters=32, dropout_2d=0.2,
                 pretrained=False, is_deconv=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.dropout_2d = dropout_2d

        if encoder_depth == 34:
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet34(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 512
        elif encoder_depth == 101:
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet101(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 2048
        elif encoder_depth == 152: #this works
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet152(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 2048
        elif encoder_depth == 777: #coded version for the pnasnet
            self.encoder = PNASNet5Large()
            bottom_channel_nr = 4320 #this unknown for me as well


        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(self.encoder.conv1,
                                   self.encoder.bn1,
                                   self.encoder.relu,
                                   self.pool)

        self.conv2 = self.encoder.layer1 #PNASNet5Large doesn't have such layers
        self.conv3 = self.encoder.layer2
        self.conv4 = self.encoder.layer3
        self.conv5 = self.encoder.layer4
        self.center = DecoderCenter(bottom_channel_nr, num_filters * 8 *2, num_filters * 8, False)

        self.dec5 =  DecoderBlock(bottom_channel_nr + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8,   is_deconv)
        self.dec4 = DecoderBlock(bottom_channel_nr // 2 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8, is_deconv)
        self.dec3 = DecoderBlock(bottom_channel_nr // 4 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 4 * 2, num_filters * 2, is_deconv)
        self.dec2 = DecoderBlock(bottom_channel_nr // 8 + num_filters * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2,
                                   is_deconv)
        self.dec1 = DecoderBlock(num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters, is_deconv)
        self.dec0 = ConvRelu(num_filters, num_filters)
        self.final = nn.Conv2d(num_filters, num_classes, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        conv1 = self.conv1(x)
        conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
        conv3 = self.conv3(conv2)
        conv4 = self.conv4(conv3)
        conv5 = self.conv5(conv4)
        center = self.center(conv5)
        dec5 = self.dec5(torch.cat([center, conv5], 1))
        dec4 = self.dec4(torch.cat([dec5, conv4], 1))
        dec3 = self.dec3(torch.cat([dec4, conv3], 1))
        dec2 = self.dec2(torch.cat([dec3, conv2], 1))
        dec1 = self.dec1(dec2)
        dec0 = self.dec0(dec1)
        return self.final(F.dropout2d(dec0, p=self.dropout_2d))
```

1) How to get how many bottom channels pnasnet has. It ends up following way:

```
...
 self.cell_11 = Cell(in_channels_left=4320, out_channels_left=864,
                            in_channels_right=4320, out_channels_right=864)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.avg_pool = nn.AvgPool2d(11, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.last_linear = nn.Linear(4320, num_classes)
```

Is `4320` the answer or not, `in_channels_left` and `out_channels_left` - something new for me

2) Resnet has somekind of 4 big layers which I use and encoders in my Unet arch, how get similar layer from pnasnet

I'm using pytorch 3.1 and this is the link to the [Pnasnet directory](https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch/blob/master/pretrainedmodels/models/pnasnet.py)

3) AttributeError: 'PNASNet5Large' object has no attribute 'conv1' - so doesn't have conv1 as well

UPD: tried smth like this but failed

class UNetPNASNet(nn.Module):
    def **init**(self, encoder_depth,  num_classes, num_filters=32, dropout_2d=0.2,
                     pretrained=False, is_deconv=False):
            super().**init**()
            self.num_classes = num_classes
            self.dropout_2d = dropout_2d
            self.encoder = PNASNet5Large()
            bottom_channel_nr = 4320
            self.center = DecoderCenter(bottom_channel_nr, num_filters * 8 *2, num_filters * 8, False)

```
        self.dec5  =  DecoderBlockV2(bottom_channel_nr + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8,   is_deconv)
        self.dec4  = DecoderBlockV2(bottom_channel_nr // 2 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8, is_deconv)
        self.dec3  = DecoderBlockV2(bottom_channel_nr // 4 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 4 * 2, num_filters * 2, is_deconv)
        self.dec2  = DecoderBlockV2(num_filters * 4 * 4, num_filters * 4 * 4, num_filters, is_deconv)
        self.dec1  = DecoderBlockV2(num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters, is_deconv)
        self.dec0  = ConvRelu(num_filters, num_filters)
        self.final = nn.Conv2d(num_filters, num_classes, kernel_size=1)

def forward(self, x):
        features = self.encoder.features(x)
        relued_features = self.encoder.relu(features)
        avg_pooled_features = self.encoder.avg_pool(relued_features)
        center = self.center(avg_pooled_features)
        dec5 = self.dec5(torch.cat([center, avg_pooled_features], 1))
        dec4 = self.dec4(torch.cat([dec5, relued_features], 1))
        dec3 = self.dec3(torch.cat([dec4, features], 1))
        dec2 = self.dec2(dec3)
        dec1 = self.dec1(dec2)
        dec0 = self.dec0(dec1)
        return self.final(F.dropout2d(dec0, p=self.dropout_2d))
```

RuntimeError: Given input size: (4320x4x4). Calculated output size: (4320x-6x-6). Output size is too small at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1525796793591/work/torch/lib/THCUNN/generic/SpatialAveragePooling.cu:63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to use `PNASNetLarge` instead o `ResNets` as encoder in your `UNet` architecture. Let's see how `ResNets` are used. In your `__init__`:

```
self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(self.encoder.conv1,
                           self.encoder.bn1,
                           self.encoder.relu,
                           self.pool)

self.conv2 = self.encoder.layer1
self.conv3 = self.encoder.layer2
self.conv4 = self.encoder.layer3
self.conv5 = self.encoder.layer4
```

So you use the ResNets up to `layer4`, which is the last block before the average pooling, the sizes you're using for resnet are the ones *after* the average pooling, therefore I assume there is a `self.encoder.avgpool` missing after `self.conv5 = self.encoder.layer4`. The forward of a ResNet in `torchvision.models` looks like this:

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.bn1(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.maxpool(x)

    x = self.layer1(x)
    x = self.layer2(x)
    x = self.layer3(x)
    x = self.layer4(x)

    x = self.avgpool(x)
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x = self.fc(x)

    return x
```

I guess you want to adopt a similar solution for `PNASNet5Large` (use the architecture up to the average pooling layer).

1) To get how many channels your `PNASNet5Large` has, you need to look at the output tensor size after the average pooling, for example by feeding a dummy tensor to it. Also notice that while ResNet are commonly used with input size `(batch_size, 3, 224, 224)`, PNASNetLarge uses `(batch_size, 3, 331, 331)`.

```
m = PNASNet5Large()
x1 = torch.randn(1, 3, 331, 331)
m.avg_pool(m.features(x1)).size()
torch.Size([1, 4320, 1, 1])
```

Therefore yes, `bottom_channel_nr=4320` for your PNASNet.

2) Being the architecture totally different, you need to modify the `__init__` and `forward` of your `UNet`. If you decide to use `PNASNet`, I suggest you make a new class:

```
class UNetPNASNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder_depth, num_classes, num_filters=32, dropout_2d=0.2,
                     pretrained=False, is_deconv=False):
            super().__init__()
            self.num_classes = num_classes
            self.dropout_2d = dropout_2d
            self.encoder = PNASNet5Large()
            bottom_channel_nr = 4320
            self.center = DecoderCenter(bottom_channel_nr, num_filters * 8 *2, num_filters * 8, False)

            self.dec5 =  DecoderBlock(bottom_channel_nr + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8,   is_deconv)
            self.dec4 = DecoderBlock(bottom_channel_nr // 2 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8, is_deconv)
            self.dec3 = DecoderBlock(bottom_channel_nr // 4 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 4 * 2, num_filters * 2, is_deconv)
            self.dec2 = DecoderBlock(bottom_channel_nr // 8 + num_filters * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2,
                                       is_deconv)
            self.dec1 = DecoderBlock(num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters, is_deconv)
            self.dec0 = ConvRelu(num_filters, num_filters)
            self.final = nn.Conv2d(num_filters, num_classes, kernel_size=1)

        def forward(self, x):
            features = self.encoder.features(x)
            relued_features = self.encoder.relu(features)
            avg_pooled_features = self.encoder.avg_pool(relued_features)
            center = self.center(avg_pooled_features)
            dec5 = self.dec5(torch.cat([center, conv5], 1))
            dec4 = self.dec4(torch.cat([dec5, conv4], 1))
            dec3 = self.dec3(torch.cat([dec4, conv3], 1))
            dec2 = self.dec2(torch.cat([dec3, conv2], 1))
            dec1 = self.dec1(dec2)
            dec0 = self.dec0(dec1)
            return self.final(F.dropout2d(dec0, p=self.dropout_2d))
```

3) `PNASNet5Large` doesn't have a `conv1` attribute indeed. You can check it by

```
'conv1' in list(m.modules())
False
```